# How can I get the value from input field and insert its value into another input?

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, input

I have a problem about inserting any input's value into the another input value.

These input value coming from selvlet is defined as below. These values are correct. I cannot emcompass them in the form.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipientNameText" name="recipientName" value="${bookOrder.recipentName}"  size="45" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipientPhoneText" name="recipientPhone" value="${bookOrder.recipentPhone}"  size="45" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="shippingAddressText" name="shippingAddress" value="${bookOrder.shippingAddress}"  size="45" />
```

My form is here

```
<form action="save_book_order" action="GET" class="form-inline">
  <input id="orderId" name="orderId" type=hidden value="${bookOrder.id}">
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="recipientNameHidden" name="recipientName" onchange="test1()"  size="45" />
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="recipientPhoneHidden" name="recipientPhone" onchange="test2()" size="45" />
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="shippingAddressHidden" name="shippingAddress" onchange="test3()" size="45" />   
</form>
```

These input values refer to the input values shown as above the form.

I want to get values from `recipientNameText`, `recipientPhoneText`, `shippingAddressText` and put them into these values but I couldn't handle with it.
How can I fix it?

Here is my javascript code.

```
function test1(){
  var recipientNameValue = document.getElementById('#recipientNameText').val();
  $('#recipientNameHidden').val();
}

function test2(){
  var recipientNameValue = document.getElementById('#recipientPhoneText').val();
  $('#recipientPhoneHidden').val();
}

function test3(){
  var recipientNameValue = document.getElementById('#shippingAddressText').val();
  $('#shippingAddressHidden').val();
}
```

When I get values from input field and check them in the servlet, these are empty.

```
String recipientName = request.getParameter("recipientName");
        String recipientPhone = request.getParameter("recipientPhone");
        String shippingAddress = request.getParameter("shippingAddress");

        System.out.println("SaveBookOrderServlet | recipientName : " + recipientName);
        System.out.println("SaveBookOrderServlet | recipientPhone : " + recipientPhone);
        System.out.println("SaveBookOrderServlet | shippingAddress : " + shippingAddress);
```

Output:

```
SaveBookOrderServlet | recipientName : 
SaveBookOrderServlet | recipientPhone : 
SaveBookOrderServlet | shippingAddress :
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand what you want but in you code some there are mistakes. 
Get the element with the specified ID like this:

```
document.getElementById('recipientNameText');
```

no need to add `#` into selector.

get value of input using javascript:

```
document.getElementById('recipientNameText').value;
```

set value of input using javascript :

```
document.getElementById('recipientNameText').value = "some value";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Please use oncick function on the text type field, not on the hidden field like this - 

 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipientNameText" name="recipientName"  size="45" onchange="test1()" />

and use javascript code like this -

        function test1(){
              var recipientNameValue = document.getElementById('recipientNameText').value;
              document.getElementById('recipientNameHidden').value = recipientNameValue;
            }
```

Comment: @TomasJonas, you are using onchange event, so you should type something in the input field and move the cursor, you will get your last input value, if you want to get input field value on load then use ready event.

Comment: How can I get last value form hidden input text?